# How to pass signal name through $value$plusargs in system verilog

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I am writing assertions in system verilog. This assertion check for a signal "lock" which is passed as an test argument through switch $value$plusargs as GPIO_SEL="test_bench.gpio"

So my code is :

```
module ab 
string abc;
$value$plusargs("GPIO_SEL=%s" , abc);
reg lock;
always @* 
begin
lock = abc;
end

endmodule
```

The problem here is that signal lock is not getting value as test_bench.gpio. Is there any way i can pass this signal value from testplaus args

Answer (score 1):

SystemVerilog is a [compiled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiled_language) language, not [interpreted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language). You can't access identifiers directly using a string. You can use compiler directives on the command line

```
module ab;

  bit  lock;
  always_comb
      begin
   lock = `GPIO_SEL;
  end

endmodule
```

Then when compiling your code use a `+define` switch

```
vlog your_file.sv +define+GPIO_SEL=test_bench.gpio
```

---

If you think re-compiling your testbench/dut is a significant burden (most tools offer incremental compilation options), and you have a fixed number of paths to access, then you can use a case statement

```
module ab 
string abc;
initial $value$plusargs("GPIO_SEL=%s" , abc);
reg lock;
always_comb
    case (abc)
      "test_bench.gpio": lock = test_bench.gpio;
      "test_bench.gpio1": lock = test_bench.gpio1;
    endcase

end
```

And you could just use a simple number instead of a string to select.

Comment: can i pass this GPIO_SEL as testplusargs? and then use lock = `GPIO_SEL; ??

Comment: No, $test$plusargs and $value$plusargs get executed at simulation.You can only create references to signal names at compilation. If you have a fixed set of signals you need to reference, you can use an `if/else` or `case` statement to select from the set of signals.

Comment: can i use reg to store these strings. foreg : string lock = test_bench.gpio; reg[8*22:0] lock_0; always @* begin lock_0 = lock; end

Comment: No. Please use +define.

Comment: one more query. when i use direct assignment in my testcase like wire lock = test_bench.gpio its working but only when i assign through $value$plusargs i am facing issue. why is it so?

Comment: +define is a compile switch right? i have multiple testcases which requires same compilation. so is there a way to handle? and GPIO_SEL is different for all testcases

Comment: If you really think recompilation is an issue, see my updated answer.

Comment: thanks dave. But i have around 100 testcase for which 100 gpios are taken. can we write a case statement for that? like for eg gpio1, gpio2...gpio100

Comment: You can write a case statement as big as you want, or write a script to write it for you. But first consider the amount you think you are saving by not recompiling for each test.

Comment: can i assign lock_0 through macro? `define sig(arg) `"arg`" 
reg lock_0;
$value$plusargs(GPIO_SEL=%s , abc);
always_comb
begin
lock_0 = test_bench.`sig(abc);
end

Comment: I tried the code using case statement but still I am facing issue in using wire in system verilog assertion property. for eg in the code which you have wriiten reg lock is assigned value. so this lock signal is then assigned to wire "wire lock_0 = lock;" and this lock_0 wire i am using in assertion. but my assertions are not able to underestand this lock_0 signal

Comment: You should be asking this as a new question. It's very difficult to see what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to conver the string to an integer type. Look at the string conversion functions: `atoi`, `atobin`, ...

for example

```
 module parg;
   string abc;
   bit [3:0] sig;
   initial begin
      $value$plusargs("GPIO_SEL=%s" , abc);
      sig = abc.atoi();
      $display("sig = %b", sig);
   end
endmodule // parg
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, But i need to use this signal "sig" in assertion. I have below assertion code: 
property check_sig ; disable iff (!sig) //add some checks ; endproperty :check_sig;
so if i use atoi conversion can i use above property assignment?

Comment: And what prevents you from using it in an assertion? The example  just shows how to assign a plusarg value to a signal. You can extend it to your needs. You asked about the signal value.

Comment: Even with the changes you mentioned the simulation is not signal value as "test_bench.gpio"

Comment: sorry, i do not understand your question any longer. There is no such signal in your example. Please provide a reproducible example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am passign GPIO_SEL through valueplusargs as GPIO_SEL=test_bench.gpio. now i am using this GPIO_SEL inside my sv test case as : string pll_lock_sel ;$value$plusargs("GPIO_SEL=%s" , pll_lock_sel) ; wire lock_0; assign lock_0 = pll_lock_sel; now this lock_0 signal is not getting value test_bench.gpio. why is it so?

Comment: ok, got it. you are trying to pass the signal name, not the value. It will not work with +args. Only strings could be passed. You cannot use +args in this case. Go with @dave_59's answer then.